# React-native app failing when added Firebase configuration to AppDelegate.m on IOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to implement react-native-firebase library to work with my react-native app (on both IOS and Android) for phone authentication.

First time I tried running it I got `Error: The [[DEFAULT]] firebase app has not been initialized!`, so i configured my AppDelegate.m file properly.

I have tried removing / reinstalling dependencies, rebuilding my app but It always gives me the same results.

But now I always seem to get the following issue when i build the app:

```
The following commands produced analyzer issues:
Analyze /Users/xxxx/WebstormProjects/myproject/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
Analyze /Users/xxxx/WebstormProjects/myproject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetInfo.m normal x86_64
```

My dependencies:

```
"firebase": "^5.7.0",
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-native": "^0.57.8",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.1.1",
```

AppDelegate.m file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

// placed below configuration before RCTRootView initialization

[RNFirebaseNotifications configure];
[FIRApp configure];
```

Podfile:

```
target 'snoozelosenative' do

   pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.7.0'
   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
   pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'
   pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
       'Core',
       'RCTAnimation',
       'RCTActionSheet',
       'RCTImage',
       'RCTLinkingIOS',
       'RCTNetwork',
       'RCTSettings',
       'RCTText',
       'RCTVibration',
       'RCTWebSocket',
       'RCTPushNotification',
       'RCTCameraRoll',
       'RCTSettings',
       'RCTBlob',
       'RCTGeolocation',
       'DevSupport',
]
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

end
```

I just want to get Firebase Phone Authentication working on both platforms, but don't know have I done wrong.

Comment: same problem for me. did you find any soloution?

Comment: @VinodRadhakrishnan for me the problem was that i had misplaced some native module or GoogleService-Info.plist (I don't remember exactly) in wrong directory. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiOGMcX6Xtw) might help you out.

Comment: thanks bro. I have fixed that issue, its because of GoogleServiceInfo.plist